# how can show related items by metakeywords in php

Tags: php, mysql

I want show related items with my item by metakeywords.i insert metakeywords for each item in database and Separate them by comma for example metakeywords for one item is: key1,key2,key3,key4 now i want show related items whit metakeywords how can i do it in php?

Comment: Could you show us some code please.

Comment: [Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3653574/)

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is to have an Item table, a Keyword table, and an Item_Keyword table.

Like this:

```
Item:
id
name
field1
blah

Keyword:
id
keyword


Item_Keyword:
item_id
keyword_id
```

To pull all the items for a keyword, you just query the Item_Keyword table:

```
SELECT *
FROM Item_Keyword
JOIN Item ON Item.id = Item_Keyword.item_id
WHERE Item_Keyword.keyword_id = whatever you want
```

Comment: i have only item table and metakeywords in my item table i can't change my table. how can now show related item ?